# Rollup + Typescript + load image as base64

Tags: typescript, rollup, rollupjs

Have a problem trying to preload image with Rollup. All the crap that should work just doesn't, have no clue why. Did anybody managed to make it working? 
Here is what I have in rollup.congig.js:

```
import image from 'rollup-plugin-image'
...
plugins: [
        image(),
        json(),
        resolve(),
        commonjs(),
        typescript({
            typescript: require('typescript'),
        }),
        (process.env.BUILD === 'production' ? terser() : {})
```

Here is what I have in the sources:

```
import CAR_IMAGE from "../resources/expand.png";
```

And in the end I get an error from rtp2 pluging which says:

**semantic error TS 2307, cannot find a module "../resources/expand.png"**

What is strange, that I'm getting the same with variety of other image-loading plugins for rollup. The path is correct, the image is there. I'm already going mad with this error =((

**Update: here is the repository with this bug reproducible:**

https://github.com/AntonPilyak/rollup-image-bug

**Update 2: have created bugs:**

https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-url/issues/22

https://github.com/alwaysonlinetxm/rollup-plugin-img/issues/5

https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-image/issues/10

How can it be SO crappy? =(((

Answer (score 5):

Replace **rollup-plugin-image** package  with this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-img) in rollup.config.js.
And add something like this below in plugins

```
plugins: [
image({
  extensions: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/,
  limit: 10000
}),........
```

Then create a file name **`declaration.d.ts`** in the root project. Add below snippet

```
declare module '*.png' {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

add this snippet in your **tsconfig.json**

```
"include": ["src","src/declaration.d.ts"],
```

Re-Run rollup in CLI. It will work!!

Comment: I found that you can still use the rollup-plugin-image package and simply create the declaration.d.ts and update the tsconfig.json as you indicated. No need to use a package that hasn't been updated for 5 years (as of this post)